# Can one prove the covering space of a manifold is second countable without using the fact that the fundamental group of a manifold is countable?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

I'm trying to prove that the covering space X of a manifold Y is a manifold of the same dimension. I was stuck on proving X is second countable, more specifically, on proving the fiber of any element in Y is at most countable.

I find a proof at [Is a covering space of a manifold second countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316622/is-a-covering-space-of-a-manifold-second-countable), but that proof is based on the countability of the fundamental group of a manifold. Could there be a more elementary approach without using this fact?

Comment: You sholud assume that $X$ is connected (which implies that also $Y$ must be connected). Otherwise there are trivial counterexamples.

Comment: Yes, I see that as part of the definition of a covering space.

Answer (score 1):

If you take $X$ to be the universal covering space of $Y$, its fiber over $p\in Y$ is in bijection with $\pi_1(Y,p)$. Thus, proving that this fiber is at most countable in general is no easier than proving that the fundamental group is at most countable.